# Leverage browser caching

Tags: php, html, caching, browser, browser-cache

According to: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching I should be using browser caching.  However, I don't know how.

Do I simply add certain tags into the html  section?  Or is thing something I need to send via to server to the client? something to do with php headers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Caching is controlled via a variety of HTTP headers. You should read Mark Nottingham's [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). You can set HTTP headers for documents outputted from PHP using the [header](http://php.net/header) function.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this in your .htaccess.

```
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: this doesn't make a difference? i am checking with pingdom.com any other suggestions?

Comment: @Rikesh: Is the code above quoted from somewhere or is it your own code? I originally though it was copy/pasted from the same place as Ashraf Malik's answer, but I see now that yours was posted years earlier. Did Ashraf plagiarise _your_ code?