# PHP GZIP more information

Tags: php, gzip

I use the plugin of google for firefox "speed test" and I have this error:

Enable compression
Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by 65.8KiB (65% reduction).

Now.. I know nothing about this subject and I want to learn more about this subject.

This is related/connected to OB ( like ob_start ) or somthing like that?

I'll be gateful to get more information and tutorials about this subject.

If there are vidoe guides its even better.

This is the full notice that I've got from Google Speed Test:

Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by 65.8KiB (65% reduction).

```
Compressing http://localhost/english/jquery.js could save 57.3KiB (65% reduction).
Compressing http://localhost/english/javascript/slider.js could save 4.0KiB (69% reduction).
Compressing http://localhost/english/style/style.css could save 3.7KiB (72% reduction).
Compressing http://localhost/english/javascript/home.js could save 853B (62% reduction).
```

Comment: I highly doubt that that's an "error". Also nothing to do with PHP, you can plug an gzip module into your Apache to compress all output.

Comment: I don't sure if it's error, but I think that GZIP can only help to my website to be faster. By the way, can I get more information about this subject?

Comment: Search for the [deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) module for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/ob_gzhandler). They have a very straight-forward example too:

```
<?php

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>This should be a compressed page.</p>
</html>
<body>
```

If the browser supports gzip, then this page will be compressed with gzip and sent compressed, after which the browser will decompress it and render it. The advantage of doing this is lowering the amount of bytes that need to be transferred.

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

- [Google website performance rules](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html)
- [Yahoo's Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.htmlhttp://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

#### Explanation

When you want to send a big file to your friend, you compress it using zip, rar, or other archiver like *gzip* to save some bytes and make it faster.

You may also do the same and compress HTML pages, JavaScript and CSS files.

Browsers do automatically handle content compressed by gzip (gzipped), assuming they get the properly compressed files with appropriate HTTP response headers.

#### Solutions

There are many options to serve gzipped content, e.g.

1. Compress the files manually and set the proper HTTP headers to serve them (e.g. in `.htaccess` or PHP script)
2. Create the gzipped versions using script
3. Use output handler to gzip output (`ob_gzhandler` or `zlib.output-compression`)
4. Use Apache module to automatically serve gzipped component, see [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)
5. Use [Google's page speed module](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html)

#### Next step

Your next step will be probably merging all those files into one, to minimize HTTP requests. There are many tools to do this automatically.

Comment: How can I gzip js, css files? By the way, can you answer me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595790/leverage-browser-caching

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way was to use [ob_gzhandler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php).  The manual stipulates that using [zlib.output-compression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression), a php.ini directive that globally enables compression is preferred nowadays.