# How to compress and optimise an Angular2 application

Tags: angular, angular-cli

### I want to make my angular-cli application faster!

[image]

Right, so I have spent a number of days updating my NG2 application to work with angular-cli. At first it was quite a frustrating experience, however, I am really seeing the light and enjoying the development process. Clearly, hard work and thought have been put into the framework.

**But my application is slow:**

According to  [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/FMJLE/https://www.fairplay.poker), my application is faster than 21% of all other sites on the internet. To be fair, this is an out of the box **ng build** and I am sure I can speed this up significantly.

[image: Play Online Poker]

My final question is: How to radically reduce the size of an angular website?

As it stands, my application, was taking 7 seconds to load (if you live in New York) so I am sure most people will have moved on before it has had a chance to load.

Clearly, I need to embark on a journey to radically increase the speed of the application but I need your help! (because I don't know what I am doing :)

What is standard practice and where do I even start sorting this out?

**PROGRESS:**

As suggestions are made I will update them here.

**1. @cyrix Suggested production ready build: ng build -prod**

The Zip file dropped by over a a meg and the new stats from Pingdom are quite an improvement from the original stats:

[image]

**2. Suggested image size reduction.**

Some of the images were a bit bigger than they should have been so these have been reduced in size. Not a major improvement, however, the stats have elevated the site into the top 73% of sites with a slightly faster load time.

[image]

**3. @yurzui suggested gzip compression, so I have enabled this. Apparently, it is working and total file sizes have been reduced by over half (609 bytes) however, this is not showing on Pingdom. I note that the grade has somewhat improved, though.**

I used [this site](https://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffairplay.poker%2F) to check compression and [this site](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html) showed me how to do it since Cpanel seemed not to work when enabled from the administration. This site also appears to be a good [gzip compression](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) resource.

[image]

**4 @Yuruzi suggested implementing a browser cache. So I did it!**

What's really interesting is the performance grade improvement, that rocks! Load time a little faster and the site is now in the top 74%. As suggested by Yuruzi I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867264/leverage-browser-caching) for guidance.

[image]

5 Thanks to @wafflej0ck on the #angularjs channel. Appears I needed to improve GZip which I have done by changing to "AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE *" type of compression as outlined [here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html).

This appears to have supercharged the site:

[image]

6 It was suggested to use AOT so I have taken a page out of [this post](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).

I went through most of the documentation, however, I was getting a world of errors and decided to leave this for a later date, hopefully when AOT is a little more stable.

[image]

I read on GitHub that the Angular-Cli comes with AOT pre-intalled and the above article is not relevant. I am not sure how true this is however I am running the following command when compiling the code: **ng build --prod --aot**

**7. Tweaked the mod_expires.c in the htaccess file.**

Performance grade has improved significantly to 98%, Load time is now under a second and the site is faster than 91% of websites tested.

The file currently looks like this:

ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

[image]

**At this point in time I can't help but think that I am now dealing with diminishing returns.**

8. Removed Unwanted fonts and unused images that were inclided in the css.

Load time has dropped and the site performance is now at 100%

[image]

9. Slow DNS and SSL

I noticed that a good deal of load time was due to DNS and SSL. To fix this I signed up with a free CloudFlare account since they have nodes pretty much everywhere, this was bound to speed a few things up...

And indeed it has. Sadly, the New York host from PingDom has been removed, but the stats from Dallas look quite promising dropping load time to well under a second!

[image]

**OTHER GOOD ARTICLES**

[This guy](https://medium.com/@areai51/the-4-stages-of-perf-tuning-for-your-angular2-app-922ce5c1b294#.apqpg117w) has a good article on optimizing angular sites as well

Comment: Hi .. do you have minified it? .. css and js and html?

Comment: First of all you application is not running in production mode.  You should also use things like UglifyJS, AoT  and CSSNano (try to use `ng build --prod`)

Comment: I agree it is not production mode http://take.ms/c49Rh You can take a look at the documentation https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md `ng serve --prod will also make use of uglifying and tree-shaking functionality` Since beta28 `--aot` defaults to true in `--prod`

Comment: Wow, just running with the --prod flag took 4 seconds off the load time. Page size has been reduced to 1.3MB... incredible.

Comment: Then try to enable gzip compression

Comment: Enable browser cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867264/leverage-browser-caching

Comment: Enabled the HTTP2 support

Comment: @yurzi Gzip compression enabled. Performance updated to the post.

Comment: @cyrix Thanks for help - working much faster.

Comment: @yurzi Dont think there is HTTP2 support with cpanel servers...

Comment: Thanks for sharing -- I've added your recommendations to my (simple) project and got "A 97" Pingdom rating.
You said you didn't apply Angular Universal to your project. This is essential. Together with server-side tweaks (like serving ahead-of-time compressed content and enforcing cache on the client) my simple site shows content in just 43ms.
I shared the concepts on github https://github.com/zertyz/zertyz-rust-playground/tree/master/web-backend-rocket

Answer (score 7):

There are some things that let you increase speed your app, among others:

1. Use **lazy loading of modules** every where possible ([link](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html))
2. build a project with the **production profile**
3. Use **Ahead of Time (AOT)** compiling ([link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)).
4. Using [Angular-Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) let you move part of rendering of project to server-side

As of 2019: **Ahead of Time (AOT)** compiling is enabled by default when the `ng build --prod` option is given.

Comment: Struggling somewhat with AOT. Tried the link you suggested however this eventually broke the app. A post on github suggested compiling the code with the --aot flag: ng build --prod --aot Whats your suggestion on this or insights? tx

Answer (score 4):

For those interested in the HTACCESS file I am using, here it is. This does force https which slows things down by about 100ms:

```
#REDIRECT ROUTES TO INDEX (fixes broken routes with angular)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
#ENABLE GZIP COMPRESSION TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# SET EXPIRE HEADERS TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

Comment: you can put this code in .htaccess file at root of project where index.html exists.